# Problem wifi with network card rtl8723be

Tags: wifi, hardware

I have installed yesterday elementary os, it's all good but i have a problem with my network card rtl8723be. Anytime i turn on my pc i should put those string in the terminal: 
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
After this wifi go good but do you have any idea to fix this, please?

Answer (score 1):

That is easy

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtlant.conf
```

It is the same for any module parameter options {module-name} {parameter-setting}  use sudo tee -a if a file exists and you just want to append to the file.  Parameter options need to be in /etc/modprobe.d/{whatevername}.conf

Answer (score 0):

Stop doing those things, follow this guide and it will work for you.

I have the same card as you, but another model (different numbering) and this guide solved all the problems I had with wifi.

You are lucky that the guide is the same as for your card, I had to change some numbers for mine.

[guide](https://connectwww.com/how-to-solve-realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal-problem-in-ubuntu/4625/)